# Class in $H^1(T^2)$ that is not dual to closed 1-dim submanifold of $T^2$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, poincare-duality

The definition for Poincaré dual $\omega$ of $N\subset M$ a $k$-dimensional submanifold is that given $i:N\to M$ we have $\int_N i^*\theta=\int_M \theta\wedge\omega$ for every $k$-form $\theta$. I know how to find the dual to a given differential form, but I am confused about the reverse process here. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but which class are you trying to dualise? Or which submanifold??

Comment: I basically was asked to show the existence of a class that is not dual to any closed submanifold.